# audio focus when Google TV pip window turns on and off

Tags: google-tv

What's the behavior suppose should be if google TV pip window turns on and off?

Any notification when pip window appearing/disappearing?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I check with the team and the answer is no. I would encourage you to file a feature request here: http://code.google.com/p/googletv-issues/issues/list

According to the docs there is no access to PIP features.

"Can I use picture-in-picture (PIP) in my Google TV Android application?
No. The picture-in-picture (PIP) feature is only available for live TV. You can't use it in your Android application, nor can you run an Android application in the PIP window."

Comment: Thanks Krispy, My question is not same as this feature request.